# Backbone model.save() sending request to root url

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

So when I call save on a new backbone model, save is sending a request to the base url defined in the model.

what I want is for save to issue a request to url/create.

the model isNew() returns true and all.

Comment: just define the `url` property with a function, use `isNew()` and return the appropriate string if it's new... i.e. `url/create`

Comment: That's simply not how your REST API is supposed to be built to work with Backbone. Your server should use the type of the request (here a `POST`) to know it's a new model, you shouldn't need an URL like '/create'. To know more about which URL will be used for each type of request => http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url.

Comment: I thought url/create sent with POST was default behavior when using model.save() and isNew returns true.

Comment: @Loamhoof, doesn't mean to say one can't do it.. i've used backbone for apps that didn't have rest interfaces.

Comment: @Loamhoof thanks dude, I was mistaken in terms of restful api route conventions.